# Can I use React components in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svelte

I am really new to Svelte, but cannot find answer to my question anywhere.

I am trying to use this React component in Svelte:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/controls/web/stack
(I guess it could be any React component and it would be the same problem)

However whenever i add it the entire app turns Blank.

Is it at all possible to import react components, if yes, how?

I have tried just to import it - which just destroys the app.

```html
<script>
    import { Stack, IStackProps } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Stack';
    let name = 'world';

</script>

<h1>Hello {name}!</h1>
<input type="text" bind:value={name}/>

<Stack horizontal tokens={{ childrenGap: 50 }}  > 
<div>test</div>
</Stack>
```

Comment: no, they are not compatible

Comment: So there are no way to use React components in Svelte?

Comment: well, you can render a react app inside a svelte app, and vice versa

Comment: Thanks Thomas, do you know where I can find some info on how to render a react app in Svelte?

Comment: Is it a substantial code base? You're probably better off rewriting them. The two paradigms are very different.

Comment: It is a substantiam codebase, it is the entre MS fabric UI. I Think i will stay whit react for now.  Thanks for all your help 

Comment: For the concrete module you mentioned there is a plain js version and a svelte too (never tried). I think its pointless to render a react app inside a svelte page (you lose the advantages of svelte and gain nothing). In a reverse case (react app and some svelte components within) you may get something for blendin two totally different approach, stil may not worth the effort.

Answer (score 6):

Artur Mustafin has answered this question in his article [React.Component wrapper for Svelte](https://medium.com/@hack2root/react-component-wrapper-for-svelte-f91134733a39).

```
<script>
  import { onMount } from "svelte";
  import React from "react";
  import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
  const e = React.createElement;
  class LikeButton extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { liked: false };
    }
    render() {
      if (this.state.liked) {
        return "You liked this.";
      }
      return e("button", { onClick: () => this.setState({ liked: true }) }, "Like");
    }
  }
  let container;
  onMount(function() {
    ReactDOM.render(e(LikeButton), container);
  });
</script>

<div bind:this={container}/>
```

Comment: I am getting an error when I run this, it says : 

`Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined (checkPropTypes.js:12)`

Answer (score 4):

With [svelte-preprocess-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svelte-preprocess-react) you're able to use react components by prefixing the tag with `react:` so `<Stack>` would become `<react:Stack>`:

```html
<script>
  import { Stack } from 'office-ui-fabric-react';
</script>

<react:Stack horizontal tokens={{ childrenGap: 50 }}  > 
  <div>test</div>
</react:Stack>
```

Answer (score 3):

Check this repo: https://github.com/jpinho/svelte-react-material

I developed a utility class called ReactAdapter that can inject any React components into Svelte. [The code is based on `RichHarris/react-svelte`.](https://github.com/jpinho/svelte-react)

Also, the project serves as a template to demo how you can have Svelte and React living side by side.

Example usage of the ReactAdapter would be:

```html
<script>
  import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
  import ReactAdapter from "./utils/ReactAdapter.svelte";
</script>

<ReactAdapter
  el={Button}
  class="mui-btn"
  children="Hello"
  variant="contained"
  color="primary"
  onClick={() => alert("hello world!")}
/>

<style>
  /**
   * Styling a React Component from within a Svelte Component.
   */
  :global(.mui-btn) {
    margin: 20px;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Notable: Svelte works well with custom elements, and so does Preact. (According to https://custom-elements-everywhere.com/ React still lacks full support.)

Comment: Old I know.. but did you publish ReactAdapter?

Comment:  I should have published it; I guess I got lazy. It's just 30 lines of code, really: https://github.com/jpinho/svelte-react/blob/main/src/utils/ReactAdapter.svelte

Perhaps I should publish a package for the sake of OSS. I can even provide some tests and examples with it.

Comment: @JoãoPinho The file is gone!